# using numbers 1 to 9 only once to equal 1 million

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Using digits 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 only once how do you equal 1 million.

Adding, multiplication, subtraction and division

Comment: Do you mean we have to get exactly one million ?

Comment: What about constructing numbers, such as 12345, from the digits? I'm pretty sure it won't be possible without that.

Comment: @gam3 multiplication by 10 you say? 1*10*10*10*10*10*10.  And do we *have* to use each digit 1 time?

Comment: @gam3:Since $1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9=45$, we only have to reverse a sum of $22$, then multiply by $10$ six times.  So (following Dason) (-1-2-3-4-5+6-7+8+9)*10*10*10*10*10*10 with many other similar solutions.

Comment: Anyone for a game of "Street Countdown"? Basically, it's like normal countdown, only it's played on the street. It can get very cold.

Comment: Using the numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 only once how can you construct the number 1 million using only addition, multiplication, subtraction and division.  Intermediate numbers can be created using addition and multiplication by 10, but these numbers can not contain factors of 10.

Answer (score 34):

Assuming you can construct number from digits one way to do it the following
$$625*4*8(19*3-7)=5^42^22^3(57-7)=5^42^5*50=5^4*2^5*5^2*2=10^6$$

Comment: How do you find such a solution?

Comment: Fiddle with it. Trial and error is a legitimate problem-solving tool.

Comment: Good answer! (25 votes)

Comment: @robjohn Yes, my first one:)

Answer (score 13):

Without some more options of operations, I don't think you can get there, as $9!=362880$. Powers would make it easy:  $(1+9)^{(2*3+4+5+6-7-8)}=(1+2*3+4+5-7-8+9)^6$

Comment: Actually you can get to $3\cdot9!/2$ by adding the $1$ to the $2$.

Comment: @joriki:  true, but still too small.

Comment: Still too small, but showing that the 9! argument does not work.

Answer (score 4):

As Ross Millikan notes, this can't be done using each digit as a complete number, so I assume that building numbers from the digits is allowed.

For example: $(7814\times2-3)\times(69-5)=1000000$

Answer (score 3):

Also assuming powers: $((-1\times3+6\times9+7-8)\times4\times5)^2$

Actually $1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5*6 + 7 + 8 + 9 = 64 = 1000000_2$

Comment: I must have missed the step where base-2 '1000000' equals one million.

Comment: @Joren If the question didn't say anything about 'one million' and just stayed that the answer should be 1000000 then it works :)

Comment: @swish Oh, so if it said that, your solution would work?  Does it say that?

Comment: What are these strange symbols: $2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$? Oh! they're that base-$1010$ encoding I've heard of.

Answer (score 2):

$$(1+2+3+4)^6 \times (7-5-9+8) = 10^6 \times 1 = 1000000.$$